# How to Keep Last 20 MB from a log file unix.(Without Logrotate and without recreating the file)

Tags: file, unix, logging, hive

I want to truncate a file(hive.log) in unix by keeping last 20 mb and as the file is being used by other applications ,i dont want to take any risk to recreate it.

I have tried unix truncate command but it truncates randomly and could not find any option to meet my requirement.

Answer (score 1):

hive uses `Log4j` to maintain there logs. So whatever you want to achieve can be done by modifying the `log4j property file`.

**File Location:** /etc/hive/conf/hive-log4j.properties

**Content You should be interested**

```
log4j.appender.DRFA=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender

log4j.appender.DRFA.File=${hive.log.dir}/${hive.log.file}

# Rollver at midnight
log4j.appender.DRFA.DatePattern=.yyyy-MM-dd

# 30-day backup
#log4j.appender.DRFA.MaxBackupIndex= 30
log4j.appender.DRFA.MaxFileSize = 256MB
log4j.appender.DRFA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
```

> log4j.appender.DRFA=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender

Says it's Daily Rotating file

> log4j.appender.DRFA.MaxBackupIndex= 30

Says it will keep 30 backups of logs.

> log4j.appender.DRFA.MaxFileSize = 256MB
>   Says the maximum file size would be 256MB.

Now you know which properties you need to change.

Comment: Thanks for the info.Currently hive.log is being redirected to /tmp/<user_name>/hive.log  and we want to redirect to some other dir due to space issue. we can't restart hive for now being a prod server ,so for time being we are thinking to add it in user bash_profile to redirect  the log to some other dir.
For above scenario we can't include the log retention  in hive log4j,so for a workaround ,we are thinking to truncate the hive.log to  keep only the last 100mbs may be for a temporary solution i.e till we get the planned outage and fix in ambari.